# Run local JS applications with I/O priveleges

Tags: javascript, node.js, io, raspberry-pi

I would like to create a local application (NOT run one via a server), coded in JavaScript or a library of it. It is to run off a Raspberry Pi (Raspbian). And most importantly, it needs I/O privileges to enable me to save data to either .txt files or file formats.

What are my options?

From my understanding, the **only** way to achieve this is to use 'node.js'. Are there any other libraries or means by which to go about achieving this? Maybe lesser-known alternatives?

---

**Extra details, in case they are relevant:**

The app will be a contact and password manager. It cannot have network access and ideally should be encrypted by Veracrypt. It should also have access to external USB devices for backups - or maybe a way to block external USB devices altogether, in case someone nefarious tries to copy my data over. I want the app to boot straight away in fullscreen mode after the Pi logs me in, but also have the ability to leave fullscreen mode. So it would need have a password prompt before the data gets unencrypted - this will be achieved via a terminal command and not in Javascript; I'm not sure if commands can be entered into the terminal via JS?

I am only including this, in case someone suggests something which for whatever reason will not work because of the above requirements.

Disclaimer: I currently don't know any Node.js. Just JS. I am considering whether I should go down the Node path for this or if there are better alternatives.

Comment: See https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html

Comment: You can exec shell command in Node using ``child_process`` API : See [exec](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback)

Comment: Thanks for the links but this is still unanswered as I don't know of any alternatives. If I should focus my efforts on Node and not look elsewhere, please let me know. Or if there are alternatives, please let me know. Also, is there anything wrong with this question? I just got blocked from asking more questions for 7 days. Suffice it to say, that doesn't help me in the slightest.

Comment: I don't know any alternatives. I can only say that Node.js is a good tool for what you want to do

Comment: Thanks! I'll focus on that for now. Considering my objective (a local app on a Pi without networking), I'll need to find a way to include a HTML and CSS UI with it. If I find a solution to this later on (there must be one somewhere), I'll try and post an update here. Provided people downvoting my posts doesn't get me blocked :p. Is there anything wrong with this question?

Comment: Bop. Is there anything wrong with this question?